# Magento search not returning results for search words men and women, but returns result for male female

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search

If I write `men` or `women` in the search bar, no items are returned in the search result. However, if I write `male` or `female`, then the search returns the items correctly. Is there any way to make Magento return those items for those search words?

Comment: are the words "men" and "women" actually in any of your products descriptions etc. Have you tried re-indexing? You can also manually add search terms under Catalog -> Search Terms

Comment: Worked when I put in search terms. If you want put an answer so I can accept. :D

Comment: The Magento LIKE search cannot find that which isn't there. For a particular search keyword to produce results, it must either appear in the attributes defined as quick search sources or be synonymed in Catalog => Search Terms. And the LIKE search also stumbles mightily on plurals of keywords, something better addressed by using Zend Lucene which is built into Magento, but in a fit of "Buh? What dat?", not used by Magento unless you buy a module to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add search terms under Catalog -> Search Terms. Reindex and cache refresh to make sure you are seeing up to date data.